# How can I solve a certain statics problem

Tags: equation-solving, engineering

Does someone have any idea how to solve it or from where to start?

[image]

Comment: You are going to want to start with a coordinate system, likely with the x-axis along structure and the y-axis perpendicular. With three unknowns, `{Ax,Ay,B}`, you are going to need three independent equations. In this problem the three equations will be the sum of the forces along the x and y directions, as well as the sum of the moments about a particular point.

Comment: You should write out the equations with "force balance" and "moment balance" principle. It should be a system of algebraic equations. Then use `Solve[]` to solve the equations.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Dropping forces on the $x$-axis:

$\qquad A_x-F \cos(\alpha)=0$

Dropping forces on the $y$-axis:

$\qquad -F \sin(\alpha)+A_y+B-F=0$

Moment of force with respect to point $A$:

$\qquad -\frac{1}{3} F \sin(\alpha) + B\, l - \frac{2}{3}F\,l=0$

```
F = Quantity[10, "Newtons"];
alfa = 45  Degree;
l = Quantity[3, "Meters"];
eq = 
  {Ax - F*Cos[alfa] == 0, 
   Ay - F*Sin[alfa] - F + B == 0, 
   -F*Sin[alfa]*(l/3) - F*(2*l/3) + B*l == 0};
Solve[eq, {Ax, Ay, B}]
```

[image: result]